# Get the value with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two different tables one with Product ID, price and barcode. The other table is with Product ID,  parent ID, price and barcode. **Product ID** is unique and **Parent ID** is only for those products which have different variables. So, I am trying to find out which formula is the best to get the barcode code for the variable products from it is Parent. Your help is much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: How price `20.5` coming for parent id `114`? No data to table1 for parent id 114.

Comment: Sorry I actually input the price for parent ID. I just made the correction in Table1. Because it is variable product, the price is different for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find parent with `VLOOKUP` from table2 and select Barcode-field from that. If that returns N/A, use barcode in Table1 with `IFNA`.

I don't have Excel in hand right now, so cannot write working forumla right now. But shouldn't be hard.

This solution excepts that if line is a parent it always has a barcode like in your example. If you have to look recursive from "grantparent" entries, it gets more complicated.

Comment: Can do this without creating additional column?

Comment: It may be very hard. You cannot overwrite original Barcode-column because you'd lose data on it.